# Oracle.DataAccess Adapter.Fill Preserve Oracle DataType

Tags: c#, oracle

In C#, when using Oracle.DataAccess Adaptor.Fill(DataSet ds) the types for the columns are .NET types such as (Byte[], string, Decimal, etc.) instead of using the original Oracle Types (BLOB, CLOB, NUMBER, etc.). Is there a way to preserve these datatypes Names in the Column type of the Table instead of using .NET types?

Comment: No.  Any .NET code would need to use the type system in .NET.  The same is true of every programming environment.  How would you possibly expect it to work otherwise?

Comment: Sorry. The question has been edited. I mean to preserve the name of the type in the column type or something like that to make sure what oracle type i am processing when I deal with a dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
        OracleConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            conn = new OracleConnection(css.ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            return conn.GetSchema(Schema, RestrictionValues);
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((conn != null) && (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed))
                conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: This answers my question.